# Entity Framework produces libSystem.native error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Currently trying to add a migration in .net 5 however, when I try to do so, I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.AnsiConsole' threw an exception.
>
> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'System.Native' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libSystem.Native, 1): image not found
>
> at Interop.Sys.Dup(SafeFileHandle oldfd)
> at System.ConsolePal.<>c.b__9_0()
> at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandleHelper.Open(Func`1 fdFunc)   at System.ConsolePal.OpenStandardOutput()    at System.Console.<>c.<get_Out>b__26_0()     at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
> at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
> at System.Console.get_Out()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.AnsiConsole..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.AnsiConsole.WriteLine(String text)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Reporter.WriteLine(String value)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Reporter.WriteInformation(String message)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)

I was able to add migrations a week ago however, I have recently tried it and am presented with this error. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Entity Framework packages, uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio. But I am still unable to get this working. Is there any suggestions?

The only thing I can possibly think of is my app updated to .NET 5.0.406 within the last week so this may be something which has had an impact?

Answer (score 0):

Updating EF Core tools helps to me:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```